# How can I automatically let API keys expire?

Tags: python

I am building an application which uses API keys during sessions. I have so far successfully generated the API keys and I can check them for validity and whether they go with the correct account and I've also added brute force protection.

My problem is that I would like to automatically let them expire after 24 hours. Right now I remove old keys when a user requests a new one to lessen the chance of someone guessing the right key, but this doesn't work for users who don't use the application again.

I was going to achieve this by scheduling a cronjob, as I read other people advising. However, the server the application will be hosted by isn't mine and the person who the server actually does belong to doesn't see the need for the automatic expiry in the first place. Which means that I would like to somehow include it in the code itself or to have a good reasoning for why he should let me (or do it himself) schedule a cronjob.

The table containing the API keys looks as follows:

```
class DBAuth(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'auth'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    api_key = db.Column(db.String(256))
    begin_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
```

And the api key generater is called as follows:

```
auth = DBAuth()
key = DBAuth.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id).first()
    if key is not None:
        db.session.delete(key)
        db.session.commit()
    api_key = auth.generate_key(user.id)
    db.session.add(auth)
    db.session.commit()
```

With the generator function like this:

```
def generate_key(self, user_id):
    self.user_id = user_id
    self.api_key = #redacted#
    self.begin_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    return self.api_key
```

My question is really two part: 
1: is my colleague right in saying that the automatic expiry isn't necessary? and 2: Is there a way to add automatic expiry to the code instead of scheduling a cronjob?

Comment: normal way is to encode expiry in the key. [This](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/json-web-tokens-with-public-key-signatures) blog post gives an example

Comment: Ah, yes, but this works with JWT tokens. We're not using those because we try to avoid importing app (restrictions made by the project owner), so we've written our own code to generate and manage keys

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment, a simple approach would be the following:

Since you already have `DateTime` objects in your schema, maybe you can add another such item say `"key_expiry_date"` that contains the current time plus 24 hours.

You can then use `"key_expiry_date"` to validate further requests

Comment: I suppose we could add some code to our authorization process which checks for the time. Thanks for the tip, I shall try and discover if I can make that work somehow.